# Select file from google drive and send to server - javascript / angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I want to select a file from google drive and send it to my server / amazon s3, guide me how can I do this? Is there any way to do this? I searched over internet not able to find a relevant one.

I done till file selection process from google drive. I need to do, once we select file from drive, either I should be able to download the file and send it to server without knowing to end user, should happen behind the screen or send directly to server.

Similarly I need to do for dropbox as well.

Please provide a solution for this.

Code for file selection from google drive

```
function initPicker() {
    var picker = new FilePicker({
        apiKey: '*******',
        clientId: "******",
        buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
        onSelect: function(file) {
            console.log(file);
            alert('Selected ' + file.title);                    
        }
    }); 
}
```